# How to store fetched JSON data in SQLite using Django/Python

Tags: python, json, django, sqlite

This is my very first attempt to work with Django Models and I keep making small steps but got stuck for the moment.

I would like to store fetched data from a third party API into my SQLite DB using Python/Django (I build my webapp on top of Django).

My idea, in theory, is as follows:

- Fetch the data using the `request` library.
- Manipulate it to make it Python conform
- extract the data by assigning it to variables
- push the data to the SQLite DB using Django `model`
- fetch the SQLite data to render the frontend

Now, this is what I have so far:

**Quotes_app/models.py:**

```py
from django.db import models

# create class to store API fetched data

class ratesEUR(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    base = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    rates = models.CharField(max_length=8)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.base
```

When I run the `models.py` I get the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
[Finished in 0.513s]
```

**Quotes_app/views.py**:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from Quotes_app.models import ratesEUR

import json
import requests

response = requests.get("http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=XXX&base=EUR")

rates_EUR = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
timestamp = rates_EUR['timestamp']
base = rates_EUR['base']
date = rates_EUR['date']
rates = rates_EUR['rates']

rates_new = ratesEUR(timestamp=timestamp, base=base, date=date, rates=rates)
rates_new.save()


def render_Quotes_app(request, template="Quotes_app/templates/Quotes_app/Quotes_app.html"):
    return render(request, template)
```

When I run the `views.py` I get the following error and the DB isn't populated:

```py
from Quotes_app.models import ratesEUR
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Quotes_app'
[Finished in 0.421s]
```

**The json response looks like follows:**

```
{
    "success": true,
    "timestamp": 1573382946,
    "base": "EUR",
    "date": "2019-11-10",
    "rates": {
        "AED": 4.047045,
        "AFN": 86.223727,
        "ALL": 123.086065,
        "AMD": 525.791674,
        [...]
}
```

**Settings.py:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'Quotes_app',
    'Wiki_app',
]
```

Besides the **above errors** I have the following questions:

1. Did I define the Table/Model properly to be able to represent the JSON data    accordingly or do I need to have some sort of nested structure or even an additional table which is linked to the other?
2. Is there an option to make the requests once every 120 seconds automatically?
3. How could I just overwrite the last data object with the newly fetched data in my database? (I don't need the outdated data anymore)
4. Is it common to make the request in the module.py file or differently?

In advance thank you **very much** for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to activate the environment, then run your Django project.

1. Did I define the Table/Model properly to be able to represent the JSON data accordingly or do I need to have some sort of nested structure or even an additional table which is linked to the other?

   Ans: - No, you should take the right datatype in model class to store the data.

```py
class ratesEUR(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False) # the timestamp data should be in the datetime format, you should convert your timestamp to datetime format and store it into the database

    base = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False) # your json date is in string format so you have to convert it into data time format

    rates = JSONField() # your json have rates value as json, so need to store it in json field

    def __str__(self):
        return self.base # this function should return string type data value only
```

2. Is there an option to make the requests once every 120 seconds automatically?

   Ans:- Yes, you can use celery package.
3. How could I just overwrite the last data object with the newly fetched data in my database? (I don't need the outdated data anymore).

   Ans:- ratesEUR.objects.filter(id=id).update(timestamp=timestamp, base=base, date=date, rates=rates)
4. Is it common to make the request in the module.py file? Or is there a different suggested approach?

   Ans:- No, it is better to write the functionality in views.py module.

Comment: I have my virtualenv well running, the above shown error persists. I updated the initial post with the 'request' logic placed to views.py. Could you guide me how to finally get the data into the SQLite backend?

Comment: If you want to fetch the records, then the query should be like this:-

rate_eur = ratesEUR.objects.all()

"rate_eur" object now has all the record objects, which you can render to your template.

Comment: Ok, but first of all I would like to populate the database with the fetched API data. But trying so results in the above mentioned errors. Could you help me to solve them? 1. is settings related in models.py and second is import module related in views.py

Comment: Just a note: the celery package is a beast to install and maintain. with many per-requisites of its own. You may want to start with a cron job running every other minute, with a Django management command to run from the command line.